# Fat friend of the cat, what am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I used to be small and fat,
>
> A good friend of the cat.
>
> Now I am slim and large,
>
> but I still need a charge.
>
> You look at me but others you see.
>
> Yet I stand still and can't flee.

What am I?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess:

> I think it is a television

```
I used to be small and fat,
```

> Older TV's were small and fat to accommodate the CRT's

```
A good friend of the cat.
```

> Cat's loved to lay on top of them

```
Now I am slim and large,
```

> Modern TV's have bigger screens but are relatively flat

```
but I still need a charge.
```

> They still require power

```
You look at me but others you see.
```

> You watch the TV to see other things

```
Yet I stand still and can't flee.
```

> It is stationary